# How to export SharePoint List to XML

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

So I am running a SharePoint Online part of Office 365, and I would like to export the "LIST" from the URL.

here is the URL:

"`URL/sites/units/Local/Demo/Lists/Project_Inventory/AllItems.aspx`"

All I am trying to do is to export the data that is on this page in a XML format, just like a RSS feed soft of.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the REST API endpoint which will display the data in your browser in XML.

URL/sites/units/Local/Demo/_api/lists/getbytitle('Project_Inventory')/items?

Answer (score 0):

You can uset the JQuery to export the list to couple of formats. I found a nice code from Microsoft gallery to export list in multiple formats.

> Using JQuery we can export SharePoint list to Excel, Word, JSON, XML,
>   SQL, CSV, TXT or PDF.This sample is tested with SharePoint Online.
>   This sample also compatible with SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2016

[Download the complete code from here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Export-SharePoint-List-to-a802fd93)

[Export SharePoint List to Excel, Word, JSON, XML, SQL, CSV, TXT or PDF](https://sptechnet.wordpress.com/2016/02/18/export-sharepoint-list-to-excel-word-json-xml-sql-csv-txt-or-pdf/)